# Graphhopper disable instructions

Tags: leaflet, graphhopper, leaflet-routing-machine

I'm using Leaflet Routing Machine libraries for routes in my project and a Graphhopper server. When inspecting network in my browser the library always gets a response from the graphhopper server with a parameter "instructions" as true but i don't use instructions in my project, how can i disable it  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out a solution, in my code; in the options of the L.Routing.Control object
i added :

```
router: L.Routing.graphHopper('', {
         urlParameters : {
             instructions : false
     }
})
```

and it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code for the Graphhopper backend for Leaflet Routing Machine](https://github.com/perliedman/lrm-graphhopper/blob/master/src/L.Routing.GraphHopper.js#L139), I read this:

```
        var computeInstructions =
            /* Instructions are always needed, 
               since we do not have waypoint indices otherwise */
            true,

        ... 

        return baseUrl + L.Util.getParamString(L.extend({
               instructions: computeInstructions,
               ...
```

You might want to get a local copy of that code, change the value of the `computeInstructions` variable, and see if everything works as expected, or if everything (or at least waypoint display) breaks as @Liedman indicated in the source code comments.